# how to replicate error for iOS from App Store crash report launch Elapsed application CPU time (seconds):

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, nsurlconnection

My iOS app is getting rejected from App Store because of 8badf00d error. On TestFlight, it works pretty fine. I want to know how to replicate my issue. My crash logs says this

```
{"app_name":"XXXXX","timestamp":"2019-07-10 09:13:23.53 -0700","app_version":"1.0.35","slice_uuid":"69c2cb31-bb04-3ed6-9e25-392ea1ca4c8d","adam_id":1447491968,"build_version":"38","bundleID":"XXXXXXX","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.3.1 
AppStoreTools:       10G3
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2019-07-10 09:13:23.4639 -0700
Launch Time:         2019-07-10 09:13:03.2745 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.3.1 (16F203)
Baseband Version:    n/a


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: XXXXXX exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.53 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 3.010 (user 3.010, system 0.000), 8% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.212, 1% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019df2a130 0x19df12000 + 98608
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019dd7a798 0x19dd78000 + 10136
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019dd7b21c 0x19dd78000 + 12828
3   CFNetwork                       0x000000019e9df000 0x19e93c000 + 667648
4   CFNetwork                       0x000000019e94014c 0x19e93c000 + 16716
5  XXXXXXX                      0x0000000102a66768 0x1027d0000 + 2713448
6   XXXXXXX                     0x0000000102a669ec 0x1027d0000 + 2714092
7   XXXXXXX                     0x0000000102a66c00 0x1027d0000 + 2714624
8   XXXXXXX                     0x0000000102a66ce8 0x1027d0000 + 2714856
9   XXXXXXX                     0x0000000102a66e88 0x1027d0000 + 2715272
10  XXXXXXX                     0x00000001027d698c 0x1027d0000 + 27020
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8c5e30 0x1ca012000 + 9125424
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8c7594 0x1ca012000 + 9131412
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8ccd20 0x1ca012000 + 9153824
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca1902dc 0x1ca012000 + 1565404
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca198874 0x1ca012000 + 1599604
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca18ff60 0x1ca012000 + 1564512
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca190850 0x1ca012000 + 1566800
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca18eb9c 0x1ca012000 + 1559452
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca18e864 0x1ca012000 + 1558628
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca1933a4 0x1ca012000 + 1577892
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca194188 0x1ca012000 + 1581448
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca19325c 0x1ca012000 + 1577564
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca197f5c 0x1ca012000 + 1597276
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8cb328 0x1ca012000 + 9147176
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca4c7ba8 0x1ca012000 + 4938664
26  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d139fc 0x1a0d08000 + 47612
27  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d1d40c 0x1a0d08000 + 87052
28  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d1cc14 0x1a0d08000 + 85012
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ddd87d4 0x19dd78000 + 395220
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019dd7d5d8 0x19dd78000 + 21976
31  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d4e040 0x1a0d08000 + 286784
32  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d4dcdc 0x1a0d08000 + 285916
33  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d4e294 0x1a0d08000 + 287380
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e32a018 0x19e280000 + 696344
35  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e329f98 0x19e280000 + 696216
36  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e329880 0x19e280000 + 694400
37  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e3247bc 0x19e280000 + 673724
38  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e3240b0 0x19e280000 + 671920
39  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a052479c 0x1a051a000 + 42908
40  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8ce978 0x1ca012000 + 9161080
41  XXXXXXX                     0x00000001027d75e8 0x1027d0000 + 30184
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019dde98e0 0x19dde8000 + 6368
```

I get following error after symbolicating

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.gmbh.oncare.careonline exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.53 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 3.010 (user 3.010, system 0.000), 8% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.212, 1% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019df2a130 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019dd7a798 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019dd7b21c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 140
3   CFNetwork                       0x000000019e9df000 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 292
4   CFNetwork                       0x000000019e94014c +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 112
5  XXXXX                        0x0000000102a66768 0x1027d0000 + 2713448
6  XXXXX                        0x0000000102a669ec 0x1027d0000 + 2714092
7  XXXXX                        0x0000000102a66c00 0x1027d0000 + 2714624
8  XXXXX                        0x0000000102a66ce8 0x1027d0000 + 2714856
9  XXXXX                        0x0000000102a66e88 0x1027d0000 + 2715272
10 XXXXX                        0x00000001027d698c 0x1027d0000 + 27020
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8c5e30 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 412
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8c7594 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3352
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8ccd20 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1540
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca1902dc __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 776
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca198874 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca18ff60 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca190850 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1064
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca18eb9c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 744
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca18e864 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 428
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca1933a4 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca194188 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca19325c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 244
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca197f5c -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 360
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8cb328 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca4c7ba8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360
26  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d139fc -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 440
27  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d1d40c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 256
28  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d1cc14 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 64
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ddd87d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019dd7d5d8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
31  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d4e040 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
32  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d4dcdc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 408
33  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a0d4e294 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e32a018 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
35  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e329f98 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
36  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e329880 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
37  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e3247bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
38  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e3240b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
39  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a052479c GSEventRunModal + 104
40  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca8ce978 UIApplicationMain + 212
41 XXXXXXX                      0x00000001027d75e8 0x1027d0000 + 30184
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019dde98e0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019dfbacd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019dfbacd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019dfbacd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019df2a0f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019df295a0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e329a10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e324920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e3240b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x000000019ecf1fac -[NSRunLoop+ 32684 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x000000019ecf1e3c -[NSRunLoop+ 32316 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca9b4494 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000019ee1e6a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019dfb72c0 _pthread_body + 128
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019dfb7220 _pthread_start + 44
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019dfbacdc thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019dfbacd0 start_wqthread + 0
```

I tried following things

1. Test app on iphone iPhone OS 12.3.1 through test flight. It works pretty well.
2. Read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: if apple has rejected your app then they must have provided some message and screenshots. you should write or upload it here!

Comment: You need to symbolicate crash log & it will give exact crash error that you got during developement in xCode.

Comment: @Lion : I don't have any screenshot. Since app crashes on start

Comment: @dahiya_boy After symbolicating crash log , I am getting stuck on this error.  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000200ebf130 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x0000000200d0f798 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x0000000200d1021c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 140
3   CFNetwork                     0x0000000201974000 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 292
4   CFNetwork                     0x00000002018d514c +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 112

Comment: @payalverma Add error in your post. In comment its hard to read and chars are also limited.

Comment: @dahiya_boy updated

Comment: Your message doesn't appear to be symbolicated correctly; lines 5-10 in the backtrace should be showing lines in your app. However, it seems that you are performing some sort of network operation that is blocking the main thread. This is timing out for Apple (does the server work in pure ipv6 environments?) and causing a watchdog kill of your app.